# PHP Declare class with a variable

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

Im trying to execute the following code

```
$our_controller = new App\Controllers\$routing->_new['controller']();
```

But Im getting 'Unexpected $routing'

And this is the class Im trying to load looks like

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
      public function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();
      }
}
```

If I type the following

```
$our_controller = new App\Controllers\HomeController();
```

Works perfectly but I must use the variable instead of HomeController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think it should work:

```
$namespace = 'App\Controllers\' . $routing->_new['controller']();

$our_controller = new $namespace;
```

Comment: Using this piece worked with minor fixes thanks (removing the () and adding it later).